# Call the same fixture multiple time in py.test

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I'm using Pytest to write some tests in Python.

I'm using the following fixture in order to create a user and user it in my test, then delete it after the test (finalizer):

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def test_user(request):
    def finalizer():
        delete_the_user()

    request.addfinalizer(finalizer)
    return user()
```

with `delete_the_user()` and `user()` two functions not detailed here.

*The problem is*: I'd like to use 2 users for some of my tests.

I've tried to call the fixture like that:

```
def test_function(test_user_1 = test_user, test_user_2 = test_user):
    # Test here
```

without success.

How can I use the same fixture more than once in a test?

Comment: I'd like to avoid parametrizing the fixture as I want to avoid a big refactoring of all the functions using that fixture

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only ways to do this I can think of are:

- Having a second fixture
- Making the fixture return a function instead (but then you'd have to refactor other functions using the fixture too).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think these are the only ways too. Using a function and parametrizing the fixture is definitively the best choice.

Comment: the second way is a bit bad if you are using the 2 test users in multiple tests (as they would be created again each time)

Comment: @GuillermoMosse That is the default behaviour of fixtures, and generally a good thing, because it keeps tests isolated from each other.

Comment: You're right! in my use case I was using fixtures with scope='module' and got blinded by that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer for this question is correct but does not come with an example. The only other example, as I write this, does not work (though it is close).

Basically, you can happily reuse a fixture if that fixture returns a function. If the object created by that fixture needs tearing down, then you can add a "finalizer". Read more about them [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html)

Taking the code from OP and adapting, your fixture ends up looking like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def test_user(request):
    user_list = []

    def create_user(*args, **kwargs):
        # CODE TO CREATE USER HERE
        user_list.append(user)
        return user

    def finalizer():
        for user in user_list:
            delete_the_user(user)

    request.addfinalizer(finalizer)
    return create_user
```

Then, for your test, instead of declaring each user as an input, you can just use the function returned by `test_user`

```
def test_function(test_user):
    test_user_1 = test_user()
    test_user_2 = test_user()
    # Test here
```

Each time you call `test_user()`, the user gets added to the same instance of `user_list`. Once the test is finished (or fails), it calls the finalizer, which has access to `user_list`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Factories as fixtures (7.1 - April 2023)

The provided answer is just a way to do it **which is not recommended** since pytest can use generators providing a more powerful fixture feature.

- You can achieve this using [Factories as fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html#factories-as-fixtures)

As per docs

> The “factory as fixture” pattern can help in situations where the
> result of a fixture is needed multiple times in a single test. Instead
> of returning data directly, the fixture instead returns a function
> which generates the data. This function can then be called multiple
> times in the test.
>
> Factories can have parameters as needed:

```
@pytest.fixture
def make_customer_record():
    def _make_customer_record(name):
        return {"name": name, "orders": []}

    return _make_customer_record


def test_customer_records(make_customer_record):
    customer_1 = make_customer_record("Lisa")
    customer_2 = make_customer_record("Mike")
    customer_3 = make_customer_record("Meredith")
```

> If the data created by the factory requires managing, the fixture can
> take care of that:

```
@pytest.fixture
def make_customer_record():

    created_records = []

    def _make_customer_record(name):
        record = models.Customer(name=name, orders=[])
        created_records.append(record)
        return record

    yield _make_customer_record

    for record in created_records:
        record.destroy()


def test_customer_records(make_customer_record):
    customer_1 = make_customer_record("Lisa")
    customer_2 = make_customer_record("Mike")
    customer_3 = make_customer_record("Meredith")
```

---

Here, a real example taken from a Chat Application I'm building https://github.com/Koubae/chatbox, code is simplified but, what it does, creating sockets on demand and close them afterwards

**Inside conftest.py**

```
import logging
import socket
import threading
import typing as t

import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def socket_create() -> t.Callable[[], socket.socket]:
    sockets: list[socket.socket] = []

    def _make():
        socket_options = [(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)]
        _socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        for opt in socket_options:
            socket_connection.setsockopt(*opt)

        sockets.append(_socket)
        return _socket

    yield _make

    for _sock in sockets:
        _sock.close()
```

**Here a test_script.py**

```
def test_tcp_server_thread_receiver_receive_msg(self, socket_create):
    total_sockets = 5
    sockets = [socket_create() for _ in range(total_sockets)]
    for _sock in sockets:
        # do whatever 
        print(_sock)
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer now when this "factory as fixture" pattern is documented and proposed as a solution for use-cases similar to OP one.

Answer (score 0):

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def test_user(request):
    user_list = []
    def create_user():
        <create_user>
        user_list.append(user)
        return user

    def finalizer(user_list):
        for user in user_list:
            delete_the_user(user)

    request.addfinalizer(finalizer(user_list))
    return create_user
```

Comment: This won't work because the argument passed into `request.addfinalizer` is not a callable. You either need to change the argument to be `finalizer` or have `finalizer(user_list)` return a function. I think the former is what you meant to do.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is to define function inside your fixture function:

Inside conftests.py

```
@pytest.fixture
def many_names():
    def name_generator():
        letters = string.ascii_lowercase
        random_string = "".join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(10))
        return random_string
    return name_generator
```

Then inside your test file:

```
def test_post_many_names(
        self, many_names
    ):        
        a = many_names()
        # now in variable a you will have first random name. For exmpale "hdfkjdhhfk"
        b = many_names()
        # when you call second time your fixture in variable b you will 
        # have second random name. For example "fjhsdfjkshksdh" 
       
        # here you put rest of your test
        ...
        assert something != something
```